# Hive twitter table running Python UDF gives Hive Runtime Error while closing operators

Tags: python, twitter, hive, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to run a Python udf in hive to make some sentiment analysis on twitter data captured with flume.

My twitter table code:

```
        CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tweets (
  id bigint, 
  created_at string,
  source STRING,
   favorited BOOLEAN,
   retweeted_status STRUCT<
     text:STRING,
     user:STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>,
     retweet_count:INT>,
   entities STRUCT<
     urls:ARRAY<STRUCT<expanded_url:STRING>>,
     user_mentions:ARRAY<STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
     hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>>,
  lang string,
  retweet_count int,
  text string,
  user STRUCT<
     screen_name:STRING,
     name:STRING,
     friends_count:INT,
     followers_count:INT,
     statuses_count:INT,
     verified:BOOLEAN,
     utc_offset:INT,
     time_zone:STRING>
       )
PARTITIONED BY (datehour int)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION  'hdfs://192.168.0.73:8020/user/flume/tweets'
```

My python code:

```
        import hashlib
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:

    line = line.strip()
    (lang, text) = line.split('\t')

    positive = set(["love", "good", "great", "happy", "cool", "best", "awesome", "nice", "helpful", "enjoyed"])
    negative = set(["hate", "bad", "stupid", "terrible", "unhappy"])

    words = text.split()
    word_count = len(words)

    positive_matches = [1 for word in words if word in positive]
    negative_matches = [-1 for word in words if word in negative]

    st = sum(positive_matches) + sum(negative_matches)

    if st > 0:
        print ('\t'.join([lang, text, 'positive', str(word_count)]))
    elif st < 0:
        print ('\t'.join([lang, text, 'negative', str(word_count)]))
    else:
        print ('\t'.join([lang, text, 'neutral', str(word_count)]))
```

And finally my Hive query:

```
        ADD JAR /tmp/json-serde-1.3.9-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar;
ADD FILE /tmp/my_py_udf.py;

SELECT
TRANSFORM (lang, text)
USING 'python my_py_udf.py'
AS  (lang, text, sentiment, word_count)
FROM tweets
```

With this query I get error while closing operators.

If I use only one variable in the python UDF the query runs successfuly if I make:

```
text = line.replace('\n',' ')
```

May it be from the SerDe in the split('\t')?

Can anyone please help? I'm suck with this for the past 10 days...

Comment: I'm still around this problem... the query only crashes when I query 2 or more columns with the text column.

If I don't query the text column, or query it alone it works...
Do you have any suggestion, please?
Many thanks in advance.